# Not able to print the string in C++

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string compress_string(string input_string)
{
    string output_string;
     int j=0;
    for (int i=0; i < input_string.length();i++,j++)
    {
            output_string[j] = input_string[i];
            cout<<"output string at "<<j<<"is"<<output_string[j];
            int count =1; 
            for (int k = i; k < input_string.length();k++)
            {
                if (input_string[i+1] == input_string[i])
                {
                    count++;
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            j++;
            cout<<"count is"<<count<<"\n";
            output_string[j]=count+'0';
            cout<<"String till now is "<<output_string<<"\n";
    }
    output_string[j]='\0'; 
    cout<<"Output string:"<<output_string<<"\n";
    printf("output string is %s\n",output_string.c_str());
    return output_string;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    string input_string; 
    cout << "Enter the string";
    cin >> input_string;
    cout<<"Compressed output is"<<compress_string(input_string);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried the above program and I see that the compressed output at the end of the program is not getting printed.
I see if I use c_str(), it does print in printf , but cout somehow is not printing the compressed output in main function and compress_string function.

Comment: Please be more specific than "it is not working".

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting ?

Comment: `output_string` is empty. `output_string[j]` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of buffer overrun, for all `j > 0`.

Comment: `output_string[j]='\0'` please don't. `std::string`s are **not** null-terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string output_string;
```

`output_string` is empty here.
Accessing its elements like below is undefined behavior.

```
output_string[j] = input_string[i];
```

`resize` it to the length of `input_string`.The you can access its individual elements;

```
output_string.resize(input_string.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reduce the range of first `for` loop from string length to string length - 1. Because of this `input_string[i+1] == input_string[i]` `i+1` check.

And the `output_string` is empty, you can not access it using index, It's a undefined behavior.

```
for (int i = 0; i < input_string.length() - 1; i++,j++) {
    .....
            for (int k = i; k < input_string.length();k++) {
                ....
            }
            ....
    }
```